# Is it possible to set the height of a fancyTree when using the column view ext

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, fancytree

I've been using the fancytree plugin for a little while now, and have managed to sort out most issues that I've come across, however I'm a bit stuck now....

I've just started using the column-view extension, and was wondering if there's a way to set the height of the table and be able to scroll within that fixed height. I'm getting back over a 100 results and need to fit the table to a specific page area.

I've tried surrounding the table with a set height div but that just cuts the table off, and have also tried limiting the size of the tbody but to no avail

To implement the column-view I used this example - http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-ext-columnview.html

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 10):

After some googling, I found an exemple where some CSS solved the problem that I had too :

```
ul.fancytree-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Complete example : https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/blob/master/demo/nav.html